# How to add the tooltips to primefaces paginator links?

Tags: primefaces

I need to add **tooltip** like below in **paginator** link button :
 -*'Page 1 out of 56'*
-*'Page 2 out of 56'* etc
I added title attribute in the `render()` method of `PageLinksRender` class. First time while page is loading it is showing the proper tooltips but after clicking the paginator link button the tool tip is gone.

Can anyone suggest me how to achive the tooltip in paginator link button even after clicking some other paginator link in the **primefaces** paginator?

Answer (score 0):

Added the title attribute to paginator link span tag present in the paginator.js under primefaces library.